# Laravel 5 New Env variable and use in layout file

Tags: php, laravel-5

So I am trying to add a new environment variable and use it in the layout file so I can hide part of menu if registration is disbled

.env

```
ALLOW_REGISTRATION=FALSE
```

layouts/apps/blade.php

```
@if (env('ALLOW_REGISTRATION',TRUE))
      ...
```

Error I am getting

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/jj/Development/app/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php) (View: /home/jj/Development/app/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)
```

Thoughts?

Comment: what does `dd(env('ALLOW_REGISTRATION'));` return for you?

Comment: I don't think the above error is due to if condition, error says you are trying to access property on variable even though variable is not object, so probably the error is caused by other code on the same page.

Comment: The dd command returns null

Comment: When I var dump the variable I get this `/home/jj/Development/AndroidAppAddicts/storage/framework/views/087bb77ee1021a12882b9d85d430c19f0d6eafd5.php:34:boolean false`

Answer (score 1):

Try `php artisan serve` and check again.  The function env() does not gets the values from the .env file when called.

Comment: So where does it get it from?

Comment: It should get from .env file. env() function receive variable form php environment getenv() funtion. You need only restart server and I think problem with .env should solved.
 Here us a link of documentation about php env
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php